# How to deserialize Excel file to 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, deserialization

I have an Excel worksheet where all the fields are strings. I would like to [de-serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) all the data from the excel file to a 2D array (matrix).

Any ideas how I can get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Excel file is built like a table, you can use ADO.NET to access your Excel file like a database and pull your data via SQL.
Excel 97-2003: http://connectionstrings.com/excel#p21
Excel 2007+: http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007#p20

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to open a .xlsx file, you should use the [Open Xml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124).

If you're trying to open a .xls file, I recommend saving yourself some headaches and checking out [filehelpers.sourceforge.net](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net).